# MSDTC Does not work in the cloud environment?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope, msdtc

I have implemented `TransactionScope` to execute queries from local computer to cloud SQL Server database in a VM. However, it throws the exception "Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed" when there is more than one connection inside Transactionscope. It's possible to telnet from local computer to VM. Also, I have configured the following.

- Allow DTC in the allowed app list
- Checked MSDTC service is Started
- Network DTC Access
- Allow Inbound
- Allow Outbound
- Allow Remote Administrator
- Allow Remote Clients
- No Authentication Required
- Enable XA Transaction
- Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transaction

Comment: FWIW, there's an official MSDTC troubleshooting tool somewhere though its name and location escapes me right now.

Comment: Apart from troubleshooting MSDTC, do you have multiple Transaction Managers, or are both transactions running on the same SQL Server?  If they are, you can avoid MSDTC by using the _same connection_ for both transactions.

Comment: @500 do you mean [DTCPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/ms-dtc-connectivity-issues)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes both transactions are on the same SQL Server but the databases are different.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, I did - thank you.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError DTCPing does not work in cloud scenario. It gives error -Problem:fail to invoke remote RPC method.

Comment: @xyz then I doubt DTC is going to do much better.... honestly, I personally would have zero expectation of DTC working over cloud boundaries, but: anything is possible!

Comment: SQL Server handle cross-database transactions without MSDTC.  Just use a single connection and you won't escalate to MSDTC.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But I have multiple connections.

Comment: You would need to use one connection to avoid MSDTC.